# python - How to use StringIO with imghdr to determine if valid image

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, imghdr

How to use StringIO with imghdr to determine if valid image

I loaded a image into

```
image_file = StringIO(open("test.gif",'rb').read())
imghdr.what(image_file.getvalue())
```

---

```
    print imghdr.what(image_file.getvalue())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/imghdr.py", line 12, in what
    f = open(file, 'rb')
TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without NULL bytes, not str
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`imghdr.what`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html) takes the optional second argument. If that is specified the first argument is ignored and the second argument is assumed to contain image bytes.

So you can change the following line:

```
print imghdr.what(image_file.getvalue())
```

with:

```
print imghdr.what(None, image_file.getvalue())
```